# I am having trouble creating a method to scan an Entire binary Tree, can you help me?(Still need help)

Tags: java, methods, binary-tree

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;              

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Node
   {
   public char iData;              // data item (key)
   public Node leftChild;         // this node's left child
   public Node rightChild;        // this node's right child


   public void displayNode()      // display ourself
      {
      System.out.print('{');
      System.out.print(iData);
      System.out.print("} ");
      }
   }  // end class Node
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Tree
   {
   private Node root;             // first node of tree

// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public Tree()                  // constructor
      { root = null; }            // no nodes in tree yet
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public Node find(char key)      // find node with given key
      {                           // (assumes non-empty tree)
      Node current = root;               // start at root
      while(current.iData != key)        // while no match,
         {
         if(key < current.iData)         // go left?
            current = current.leftChild;
         else                            // or go right?
            current = current.rightChild;
         if(current == null)             // if no child,
            return null;                 // didn't find it
         }
      return current;                    // found it
      }  // end find()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   // If (current.leftChild != '+' && current.rightChild != '+')
   //  if ( current.leftChild != '+')                         if(current.rightChild != '+')
   // 
   //       



   public void insert(char id)
      {
      Node newNode = new Node();
      Node plusNode = new Node();
      // make new node
      newNode.iData = id;
      plusNode.iData = '+';         // insert data
      if(root==null)                // no node in root
         root = newNode;
      else                          // root occupied
         {
         Node current = root;       // start at root
         Node parent;
         while(true)                // (exits internally)
            {
            parent = current;
            if(id < current.iData)  // go left?
               {
               current = current.leftChild;               
               if(current == null)  // if end of the line,
                  {                 // insert on left
                  parent.leftChild = newNode;
                  if(parent != root);
                  {parent.rightChild= plusNode;}
                  return;
                  }
               }  // end if go left
            else                    // or go right?
               {
               current = current.rightChild;
               if(current == null)  // if end of the line
                  {                 // insert on right
                  parent.rightChild = newNode;
                  if(parent != root);
                  {parent.leftChild = plusNode;}
                  return;
                  }
               }  // end else go right
            }  // end while
         }  // end else not root
      }  // end insert()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean delete(char key) // delete node with given key
      {                           // (assumes non-empty list)
      Node current = root;
      Node parent = root;
      boolean isLeftChild = true;

      while(current.iData != key)        // search for node
         {
         parent = current;
         if(key < current.iData)         // go left?
            {
            isLeftChild = true;
            current = current.leftChild;
            }
         else                            // or go right?
            {
            isLeftChild = false;
            current = current.rightChild;
            }
         if(current == null)             // end of the line,
            return false;                // didn't find it
         }  // end while
      // found node to delete

      // if no children, simply delete it
      if(current.leftChild==null&& current.rightChild==null)
      {
          if(current == root)
              root = null;
          else if(isLeftChild)
              parent.leftChild = null;
          else 
              parent.rightChild = null;
      }



      // if no right child, replace with left subtree
      //put your code here

      else if(current.rightChild==null)
          if(current == root)
              root = current.leftChild;
          else if (isLeftChild)
              parent.leftChild = current.leftChild;
          else
              parent.rightChild = current.leftChild;


      // if no left child, replace with right subtree
      //put your code here

      else if(current.leftChild==null)
          if(current == root)
              root = current.rightChild;
          else if(isLeftChild)
          parent.leftChild=current.rightChild;
          else
              parent.rightChild = current.rightChild;


      else  // two children, so replace with in order successor
         //put your code here
      {
          Node successor = getSuccessor(current);

          // if connect parent of current to successor instead
          if(current == root)
              root = successor;
          else if (isLeftChild)
              parent.leftChild = successor;
          else
              parent.rightChild = successor;
          // connect successor to current's left child
          successor.leftChild = current.leftChild;
      }



      // (successor cannot have a left child)
      return true;                                // success
      }  // end delete()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   // returns node with next-highest value after delNode
   // goes to right child, then right child's left descendants
   private Node getSuccessor(Node delNode)
      {
      Node successorParent = delNode;
      Node successor = delNode;
      Node current = delNode.rightChild;   // go to right child
      while(current != null)               // until no more
         {                                 // left children,
         successorParent = successor;
         successor = current;
         current = current.leftChild;      // go to left child
         }
                                           // if successor not
      if(successor != delNode.rightChild)  // right child,
         {                                 // make connections
         successorParent.leftChild = successor.rightChild;
         successor.rightChild = delNode.rightChild;
         }
      return successor;
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void traverse(int traverseType)
      {
      switch(traverseType)
         {
         case 1: System.out.print("\nPreorder traversal: ");
                 preOrder(root);
                 break;
         case 2: System.out.print("\nInorder traversal:  ");
                 inOrder(root);
                 break;
         case 3: System.out.print("\nPostorder traversal: ");
                 postOrder(root);
                 break;
         }
      System.out.println();
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   private void preOrder(Node localRoot)
      {
      if(localRoot != null)
         {
         System.out.print(localRoot.iData + " ");
         preOrder(localRoot.leftChild);
         preOrder(localRoot.rightChild);
         }
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   private void inOrder(Node localRoot)
      {
      if(localRoot != null)
         {
         inOrder(localRoot.leftChild);
         System.out.print(localRoot.iData + " ");
         inOrder(localRoot.rightChild);
         }
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   private void postOrder(Node localRoot)
      {
      if(localRoot != null)
         {
         postOrder(localRoot.leftChild);
         postOrder(localRoot.rightChild);
         System.out.print(localRoot.iData + " ");
         }
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void displayTree()
      {
      Stack globalStack = new Stack();
      globalStack.push(root);
      int nBlanks = 32;
      boolean isRowEmpty = false;
      System.out.println(
      "......................................................");
      while(isRowEmpty==false)
         {
         Stack localStack = new Stack();
         isRowEmpty = true;

         for(int j=0; j<nBlanks; j++)
            System.out.print(' ');

         while(globalStack.isEmpty()==false)
            {
            Node temp = (Node)globalStack.pop();
            if(temp != null)
               {
               System.out.print(temp.iData);
               localStack.push(temp.leftChild);
               localStack.push(temp.rightChild);

               if(temp.leftChild != null ||
                                   temp.rightChild != null)
                  isRowEmpty = false;
               }
            else
               {
               System.out.print("--");
               localStack.push(null);
               localStack.push(null);
               }
            for(int j=0; j<nBlanks*2-2; j++)
               System.out.print(' ');
            }  // end while globalStack not empty
         System.out.println();
         nBlanks /= 2;
         while(localStack.isEmpty()==false)
            globalStack.push( localStack.pop() );
         }  // end while isRowEmpty is false
      System.out.println(
      "......................................................");
      }  // end displayTree()


  /*  public void Play()
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      int cont = 1;

      while (cont ==1)
      {
      Node newNode = new Node();
      System.out.println("Please enter a char ");
      char input = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
      newNode.iData = input;

     int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to enter another? ");

      if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)  
      {

      }

      else if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
      {
          cont = 0;
      }


      }

   }*/


   public void fixRoot()
   {

       Node current = root;

       if(current.iData != '+')
       {
           insert(current.iData);
       }
       current.iData = '+';



   }

   public void fixTree()
   // Look at root of the binary tree
   // If the root is a char besides '+', insert it in the tree again
   // use same logic in order to rewrite the whole tree with transverse
   {   Node current = root;


      if (current.leftChild.iData != '+' && current.rightChild.iData != '+')      
      {
        if ( current.leftChild.iData != '+')
        {
            if(current.iData != '+')
           {
               insert(current.iData);
           }
           current.iData = '+';
        }
          if(current.rightChild.iData != '+')
          {
              if(current.iData != '+')
           {
               insert(current.iData);
           }
           current.iData = '+';
          }
      }


}
   public void transverseFix()
   {
       fixTree(root);
   }

  public void fixTree(Node current)
  //Transverse through the tree, node by node
  //At each location, check if leftChild or rightChild does not = '+'

   {
     if (current == null) return;

     fixTree(current.leftChild);

     if(current.iData != '+')
     {
           insert(current.iData);
           current.iData = '+';
     }
     if (current.rightChild != null)
    //{
   //    System.out.println(current.rightChild.iData);
   //    displayTree();
    // }
  //  fixTree(current.rightChild); 





   }

// -------------------------------------------------------------
   }  // end class Tree
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class TreeApp
   {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
      {
      char value;
      Tree theTree = new Tree();
      int cont = 1;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);          
      do
      {
      System.out.println("Please enter a char ");
      char input = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
      theTree.insert(input);     
      System.out.println("Enter more?");
      String input2 = keyboard.next();
      if (input2.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
      {
          cont = 2;
      }
        }while(cont == 1);

      theTree.displayTree();
      System.out.println("");
      theTree.fixRoot();
      theTree.displayTree();
      System.out.println("");
     // theTree.transverseFix();
      theTree.displayTree();








       //Testing without question
       // theTree.insert('a');
       // theTree.insert('z');
       //  theTree.insert('c');
       //   theTree.fixRoot();
       //  theTree.transverseFix();






      /*while(true)
         {
         System.out.print("Enter first letter of show, ");
         System.out.print("insert, find, delete, or traverse: ");
         int choice = getChar();
         switch(choice)
            {
            case 's':
               theTree.displayTree();
               break;
            case 'i':
               System.out.print("Enter value to insert: ");
               value = getChar();
               theTree.insert(value);
               break;
            case 'f':
               System.out.print("Enter value to find: ");
               value = getChar();
               Node found = theTree.find(value);
               if(found != null)
                  {
                  System.out.print("Found: ");
                  found.displayNode();
                  System.out.print("\n");
                  }
               else
                  System.out.print("Could not find ");
                  System.out.print(value + '\n');
               break;
            case 'd':
               System.out.print("Enter value to delete: ");
               value = getChar();
               boolean didDelete = theTree.delete(value);
               if(didDelete)
                  System.out.print("Deleted " + value + '\n');
               else
                  System.out.print("Could not delete ");
                  System.out.print(value + '\n');
               break;
            case 't':
               System.out.print("Enter type 1, 2 or 3: ");
               value = getChar();
               theTree.traverse(value);
               break;
            default:
               System.out.print("Invalid entry\n");
            }  // end switch
         }  // end while*/
      }  // end main()
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public static String getString() throws IOException
      {
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String s = br.readLine();
      return s;
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public static char getChar() throws IOException
      {
      String s = getString();
      return s.charAt(0);
      }
//-------------------------------------------------------------
   public static int getInt() throws IOException
      {
      String s = getString();
      return Integer.parseInt(s);
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   }  // end class TreeApp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class AlphabatizeLink {

}
```

The modifications i did took place in, insert(), and the functions at the bottom starting with,play(). The end result i am trying to get is, Each Char that is not a '+' as a leaf, and each parent having 2 children, whether it is a char that is a letter or a char that is '+'.

So the first part, the user enters input and those are put in the tree as  a char. Then the fix root method re-inserts the root further down the tree and making the root a '+'. I had the same idea with the rest of the tree, to transverse the tree and instead of printing, fixing it but i get a out of memory error. When you take off the // off theTree.Transverse() in the main and off the lines of code in the actual method, you will see the error.

Comment: what class is 'current' of? LinkedList has no leftChild variable.

Comment: what is the insert function call doing ?

Comment: What do you mean by leftchild and rightchild? Are you sure you're not confusing LinkedList with BinaryTree? And does the function "insert" have anything to do with insertion of nodes?

Comment: Yes, i meant binary tree. The functions of it does not matter, i am trying to make it work, Ignore what is in there except for current. Current is where the computer is currently looking.

Comment: So you simply want to iterate over every node. What method is used is not the concern right?

Comment: Yes, i want to iterate over every single node and execute the code shown above. Where current would be the actual node that it is viewing.

Answer (score 3):

```
void f( Node current )
{
  if (current == null) return;

  f(current.left);

  // your code goes in here.

  f(current.right);

}
```

Call the above function with **root** node as the actual parameter.

Comment: Seems i will have to go about this problem another way, i just get a null pointer exception in all the places i implement it.

Comment: You cant get a null pointer exception unless you're doing something wrong. Maybe you didn't initialize the tree properly. Can you post the full code your using?

Comment: Sure thing, Here is a link to pastebin.... pastebin.com/9HehtKif

Comment: The inOrder, preOrder, postOrder functions are correct. What are you having problems with?

Comment: When i input the code that i have entered, in the position you said to. I get a null pointer exception On the lines in which that codes is executed.

Comment: I will redo the question and post all the needed code and a description of what i am trying to do tonight. Thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: if (current == null) return; If this condition is false, current is not null. So its impossible that you get a NullPointerException because current is null (which can't be). Must be one of the objects defined by you which are creating trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The standard structure of a recursive function (in pseudocode) for this kind of scenario is this:

```
recurse(current)
{
    if(current is null) then return

    recurse(current.left)

    operateOnCurrentNode(current)

    recurse(current.right)
}
```

The reason you are getting a null pointer is that, inside your "fixTree(Node current)" recursive method call, you have code like this:

```
if (current.leftChild.iData != '+' || current.rightChild.iData != '+')
```

If current has a value but no children, (for example, a leaf node with iData = '+',) then the above line will immediately break. Your code makes the assumption that, if your current node has a value, then its left and right pointers will also have a value. Obviously, for leaf nodes, this is not true. 'leftChild' will be null, at which point you're effectively saying:

```
if (current.NULL.iData != '+' || current.NULL.iData != '+')
```

"NULL" cannot have an "iData" field. NullPointerException. :)

The best way to sort out these sorts of problems is to make sure that any code in the recursive function is *only* looking at what is currently in that node, not what is in each of its children. (That's not a hard and fast rule, but it's a very good rule of thumb.)

I'd give you a worked example, but I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure what it is that your recursive code is *supposed* to do. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few places in the Tree class you use variables before you check if they are null, this is obviously not smart. This example will give NullPointerException if root == null

```
public Node find(char key)
{
    Node current = root;
    while (current.iData != key)            // Exception if root == null
    {l
        if (key < current.iData) 
            current = current.leftChild;
        else
            current = current.rightChild;

        if (current == null)                // Checking for null is futile by now
            return null;
    }
    return current;
}
```

That goes for this function too:

```
public boolean delete(char key)
{
    Node current = root;
    Node parent = root;
    boolean isLeftChild = true;

    while (current.iData != key)        // Exception if root == null
    {
```

Also in insert() you have:

```
if (parent != root);
{
    parent.rightChild = plusNode;
}

if (parent != root);
{
    parent.leftChild = plusNode;
}
```

Notice those semicolons? I doubt you want those there. If this doesnt help you, you will have to be more clear about your problems. Try shortening your code to the minimum that will reproduce the error.